# Some iPad users cannot see my iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store

I have a weird issue where I can see the Simplecue application on my iPad but others in my team cannot see it, we've also had some customers email us saying they cannot find it as well.

All of the users can find the application via their iPhones, iPods, and iTunes. So for a temporary solution, we've asked users to download and sync via iTunes to their iPad.

The only difference between my iPad and others, is my iPad is a 1st generation iPad. Should this matter?

Answer (score 1):

If your app requires features that the iPad 1 does not support (front-facing or indeed any camera, iOS6) then it will not be visible in the App Store on that device.

Comment: but this is the other way around, I have a iPad 1 and can see the application on the App Store, other iPads can't see it

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread the question. In that case, I don't know what's going on. I'll leave this answer around since it is useful information anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There may reportedly be bugs with the current (Nov 2012, iOS 6.0.1) App Store app on the iPad, where it won't show, via search, some apps that have been released for sale by the developer.

A 1st gen iPad runs the older iOS 5.1, and thus may have a more reliable version of the App Store app.

But a direct itms URL from your web page (as viewed with an iPad's Safari) to the App Store app may work on both iPads.